# NSTextAttachment() Extra Properties

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am wanting to add extra info onto some of the images I add to my `UITextView`. The class is `NSTextAttachment()`. I need my images to have some `String` descriptions so the app knows what's inside the image. How do I add this extra functionality? Is it through an `Extension`?

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = image
attachment.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)
// Extra properties wanted
attachment.description = "add in info about what is in attachment"
attachment.moreInfo = "some more info about the attachment"
```

Comment: Add your info thru custom attributes on the attributed string itself, not thru the text attachment.

Comment: @matt Would you be able to indulge me with an example please? I've been trying and am really unsure how to do this...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can only be using NSTextAttachment because you've got an NSMutableAttributedString. Well, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring/1414304-addattributes lets you add attributes to any stretch of that attributed string. No law says you have to use the attributes that the layout engine knows about. You can have a `description` attribute and a `moreInfo` attribute, and give them any values you like. Now you've stored custom info in your string at a desired location.

Comment: I need the attributes so later on I can call on them. For example what's the description for image 1. I'm not understanding how you are saying to do this? I can't add an extension to the actual attachment and can only add the info to a range? Is that what you're saying?

Answer (score 1):

```
class EmojiTextAttachment:NSTextAttachment{    
}
private var EmotagAssociationKey:String? = nil
extension EmojiTextAttachment{

    var emoticonName:String?{
        get {return objc_getAssociatedObject(self,&EmotagAssociationKey) as? String ?? ""}
        set {objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &EmotagAssociationKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) }
    }
}
```

It's been a while, but my solution is up.
Extends `NSTextAttachment`
You can add parameters with `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject`

When using it, use `EmojiTextAttachment` instead of `NSTextAttachment`.

```
  let emoticon:EmojiTextAttachment = EmojiTextAttachment()
                    let image = UIImage(named: myImage) as UIImage!
                    emoticon.image = image?.resizeSelf(newWidth, newHeight)
                    emoticon.emoticonName = emoname
```

The docs of `objc_getAssociatedObject` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418865-objc_getassociatedobject